# In a certain country ,$100$ roads lead out of each city and one can travel along those roads from one city to the other

Tags: combinatorics

In a certain country ,$100$ roads lead out of each city and one can travel along those roads from one city to any other . One road is closed for repair work . Prove that one can still get from any city to another .
The solution given on the book is as follows:

> If road $AB$  has closed then it is enough to prove that we can still get from $A$ to $B$. If this were not true, then in the connected component containing  $A$ all the  vertices other than $A$ would be even . The situation of having exactly one odd vertex in a connected component contradicts the statement "A graph must have an even number of odd vertices"

However, I am not getting the idea of the solution ...I dont get what does it mean by saying " If this were not true, then in the connected component containing  $A$ all the  vertices other than $A$ would be even " ...the path from A to B is deleted so...the degree of B is also odd...so, how does they draw this conclusion ...

Comment: If one cannot go from $A$ to $B$, then $B$ is not in the connected component of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be the graph in question.

Suppose if we closed $AB$ we could not get from $A$ to $B$.

That means we could divide $G$ into two separate components: one containing $A$ and one containing $B$, just by deleting $AB$ (that is: closing the road between $A$ and $B$).

Anyway, suppose we *could* do this.

Let $S$ and $T$ be collections of vertices of the graph $G$, which are joined by a bridge $AB$, so that $A$ is a vertex of $S$ and $B$ is a vertex of $T$.

(In this context, a "bridge" is an edge of a graph that, if you remove it, separates the graph into two disconnected components.)

Thus when $AB$ is deleted, and we can no longer get from $A$ to $B$, that means $S$ and $T$ make two separate graphs.

Before we remove edge $AB$ (that is, close the road):

- All vertices in $S$ are even, including $A$ which is incident to the bridge $AB$.
- All vertices in $T$ are even, including $B$ which is incident to the bridge $AB$.

But when you delete $AB$:

- all the vertices in $S$ except $A$ are even, while $A$ is odd.
- all the vertices in $T$ except $B$ are even, while $B$ is odd.

Hence $S$ and $T$ are both graphs which do *not* have an even number of odd vertices.

Because that cannot happen, it cannot be the case that deleting $AB$ causes $S$ and $T$ to be disconnected.

Hence you *must* be able to get from $A$ to $B$ without needing to use the road $AB$.

Comment: Thank you so much! But can you please explain how after deletion of $AB$ we do get two connected components....I mean whats the gurantee that the graph resulting will be a connected graph component of the original graph...

Comment: $G$ is a connected graph, which means you can get from any node (city) to any other node. Suppose you delete $AB$ and you *can't* now get from $A$ to $B$ via another route. That means the subgraphs containing $A$ and $B$ are **disconnected**, which means they are separate graphs in their own right. The fact that you *can't* disconnect $A$ and $B$ by removing one edge (that is, "closing one road") means there must be another route from $A$ to $B$ (travelling via other cities, probably) which means that you can't disconnect the graph by deleting one edge.

Comment: ....How after deletion of $AB$ we do get two graphs $S$ and $T$ such that all of them have even vertices except $A$(in $S$ ) and $B$ (in $T$) as they are only the odd vertices...but if $S$ has $A$ and $B$ both then it has an even number of odd vertices ...are u insisting on that $S$ should exclude $B$ but then again all other vertices in $S$ will have $ 99$ edges and then it depends upon the number of vertices in S if it is even then its possible but if odd then it's not possible....I am not quite getting this....

Comment: $S$ does *not* have both $A$ and $B$, $S$ just has $A$. 1) We want to prove you can't disconnect $G$ into two parts, one containing $A$ and one containing $B$. (Because if you did that, then you would *not* be able to get from $A$ to $B$ without using the closed road $AB$.) 2) So we suppose the opposite, that you *can* disconnect $G$ into two parts by closing the road $AB$, and from that we prove something impossible. (In this case, the "impossible" thing we prove is that we have $2$ graphs, both with an odd number of odd vertices.) Continued ...

Comment: 3) We deliberately construct a graph, in our heads, which contains two bits that would be disconnected if you removed the edge $AB$, which is the one which connects $A$ and $B$. (Then $A$ would have $99$ edges coming from it, and $B$ would also have $99$ edges coming from it.) So, what we do is, having pictured in our head a graph which has $A$ and $B$ joined by $AB$, we call $S$ the graph representing all the cities connected to $A$ (on one side of $AB$), and we call $T$ the graph representing all the cities connected to $B$ (on the other side of $AB$). Continued ...

Comment: 4) With that picture in our head, we now remove $AB$. *Because* we made the supposition that you can no longer get from $A$ to $B$ (what we did in 2 above), it follows that $S$ and $T$ are now disconnected from each other. That is, $S$ and $T$ both now form connected graphs in their own right. 5) But because a graph can't have only one odd node (which you would get if you deleted $AB$), that is, $S$ on one side containing $A$ and $T$ on the other side containing $B$), it is impossible for $S$ and $T$ to exist. So there *has* to be at least one other edge connecting $S$ and $T$) ... continued

Comment: ... than just $AB$.

Comment: @Franklin yes. Job done.

Comment: ..Exactly! We are deliberately constructing such a graph in our head such that for the sake of contradiction ...when we delete AB then the two becomes separated as if those two graphs were connected just by a bridge AB but now it is deleted then only we get the contradiction...this was the idea right?

Comment: Thank you so much! "Just an $AB$", was it? I mean only through $AB$ those two graphs are connected...is this what u tried to imply upon right?...

Comment: @Franklin I have added the "reductio ad absurdum" construction, the "suppose the opposite, and from that prove an impossibility" to the answer I originally gave.

Comment: ...."I mean only through AB those two graphs are connected...is this what u tried to imply upon right?..."Then this implication is correct right? Yeah, the edit is good ...Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Franklin Yes that's what I said. Sorry, I must have taken it for granted that you know what "bridge" means. I'll explain that in the question.

Comment: no...I was just verifying the idea ...its alright ....Thanks a lot!